# Java generics return type

Tags: java, android, generics

```
    public class Signal<T>{
        public void addListener(T listener){
            // do some thing
        }
    }

    public static <T> Signal<? extends T> inject(Class<? extends T> type) {
        // do some thing and return 
    }

    public void execute(MyInterface callback){
        Signal<? extends MyInterface> signal = inject(callback.getClass());
        signal.addListener(callback); // Compiler error
    }
```

I got a compiler error in the last raw, any idea how to fix it? I don't mind changing the implementation of `inject` or `Signal` class, my goal is to make `execute` method to work as it is now.

Comment: Try changing `sinal.add(callback);` to `signal.addListener(callback);` and post the compiler output.

Comment: `public <T extends MyInterface> execute(T callback)`

Comment: @immibis not working, and I also trying to find a solution without changing the execute method.

Comment: You would also need to change `Signal<? extends MyInterface>` to `Signal<T>`

Comment: Why does `inject` use `extends`? Wouldn't it make more sense to do `public static <T> Signal<T> inject(Class<T> type)`? Then again, you haven't provided the implementation for `inject`...

Comment: I assume `sinal` is a typo in your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
    public static <T> Signal<T> inject(Class<? extends T> type) {
        return null;
    }

    public void execute(MyInterface callback){
        Signal<MyInterface> signal = inject(callback.getClass());
        signal.addListener(callback);
    }
```

Comment: Seems potentially unsafe. How does `inject` know not to return a `Signal<Object>`?

Comment: @immibis See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: @Dogs I think @immibis refers to `Class<? extends Object> clazz = callback.getClass(); Signal<Object> signal=inject(clazz); signal.addListener(42);` which compile without warnings.
Perhaps it would be better `Signal<T> inject(Class<T> type)` requiring an explicit unchecked cast on part of the caller `inject((Class<MyInterface>)clazz).addListener(callback);`.

This issue is because of `Signal` being a consumer of `T` (then returning `Signal<? extends T>` doesn't help, as the OP stated), but we only know the upper bound from `callback.getClass()`.